# C# programming error questions?

Tags: c#

I am in a basic C# programming class, and I have been understanding everything up until I had to do the following exercise. If someone could check my code and help me out, that would be fantastic. I'm getting three different errors (CS1620, CS0266, and CS1955) in this code. I had a classmate try to help me out, but that did not work out so well.

Here is the exercise prompt:

Piecework workers are paid by the piece. Workers who produce a greater quantity of output are often paid at a higher rate.

Form: Use text boxes to obtain the person’s name and the number of pieces completed. Include a Calculate command button to display the dollar amount earned. You will need a Summary button to display the total number of pieces, the total pay, and the average pay per person. A clear button should clear the name and the number of pieces for the current employee.

Include validation to check for missing data. If the user clicks on the Calculate button without first entering a name and number of pieces, display a message box. Also, you need to make sure to not display a summary before any data are entered; you cannot calculate an average when no items have been calculated. You can check the number of employees in the Summary event procedure or disable the Summary command button until the first order has been calculated.

```
Pieces completed     Price paid per piece for all pieces
      1-199                    .50
    200-399                    .55
    400-599                    .60
    600 or more                .65
```

Code:

```
public partial class pieceworkForm : Form
{
    //Declare variables.
    int tpiece = 0;
    int numemp = 0;
    float tpay = 0;

    public pieceworkForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Closes form.
        this.Close();
    }

    private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Prints form.
        printForm1.PrintAction = System.Drawing.Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPreview;
        printForm1.Print();
    }

    private void calcButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Converts pieces to integer.
        int pieces = 0;
        pieces = int.Parse(piecesTextBox.Text.Trim());

        //Calculates pay based on number of pieces completed. 
        float pay = calcButton(pieces);

        //Display the formatted text in the pay label
        payMaskedTextBox.Text = string.Format("C", pay);
        payMaskedTextBox.Visible = true;

        //Counts employees on click.
        numemp = numemp + 1;

        //Total pieces made.
        tpiece = tpiece + pieces;

        //Total pay.
        tpay += pay;

        //Enable summary button.
        sumButton.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Clears form.
        empTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
        piecesTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
        payMaskedTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void callButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Confirm clear.
        if ((MessageBox.Show("Do you want to clear this form?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes))
        {
            // Call the regular "Clear" button handler, as if it had been clicked as well.
            clearButton_Click(sender, e);

            //Reset everything to zero.
            tpiece = 0;
            tpay = 0;
            numemp = 0;

            // Make summary groupbox invisible.
            summaryGroupBox.Visible = false;

            // And disable summary button until new pay is entered.
            sumButton.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

    private void empTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Show message if field is empty.
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(empTextBox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter an employee name.");
        }
    }

    private void piecesTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Show messgae if field is empty.
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(piecesTextBox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the number of pieces completed.");
        }
    }

    private float calc(int pieces)
    {
        float pay = 0;
        switch (pieces)
        {
            case 0:
                pay = 0;
                break;
            case 1: // 1 to 199
                pay = pieces * 0.5;
                break;
            case 2: // 200 to 399
                pay = pieces * 0.55;
                break;
            case 3: // 400 to 599
                pay = pieces * 0.6;
                break;
            default:
                pay = pieces * 0.65;
                break;
        }
        return pay;
    }

    private void SetcalcButtonState()
    {
        // Assume false 
        calcButton.Enabled = false;

        // Check for non-empty text
        if (((empTextBox.Text.Trim().Length > 0) & (piecesTextBox.Text.Trim().Length > 0)))
        {
            int pieces = 0;
            // TryParse will return true if the text is good as a number
            if ((int.TryParse(piecesTextBox.Text.Trim(), pieces)))
            {
                calcButton.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void sumButton_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //Show total pieces nd pay.
        tpieceMaskedTextBox.Text = string.Format("{0}", tpiece);
        tpayMaskedTextBox.Text = string.Format("C", tpay);
        //Calculate and show average pay per employee.
        avgMaskedTextBox.Text = string.Format("C", tpiece / numemp);
        // Make the whole summary box visible
        summaryGroupBox.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

The specific problem areas are as follows:

> CS1955    Non-invocable member 'pieceworkForm.calcButton' cannot be used like a method.

```
float pay = calcButton(pieces);
```

> CS0266    Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
private float calc(int pieces)
{
        float pay = 0;
        switch (pieces)
        {
            case 0:
                pay = 0;
                break;
            case 1: // 1 to 199
                pay = pieces * 0.5;
                break;
            case 2: // 200 to 399
                pay = pieces * 0.55;
                break;
            case 3: // 400 to 599
                pay = pieces * 0.6;
                break;
            default:
                pay = pieces * 0.65;
                break;
        }
        return pay;
}
```

> CS1620    Argument 2 must be passed with the 'out' keyword.

```
 if ((int.TryParse(piecesTextBox.Text.Trim(), pieces)))
 {
     calcButton.Enabled = true;
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand your switch-case statement. For example, you're basically saying `if pieces == 2`, `pay = 1.10`. I don't see how you're checking those ranges. Any number of pieces above 3 will go to the default block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CS1955 Non-invocable member 'pieceworkForm.calcButton' cannot be used
>   like a method.

Instead of calling a method you are calling an event handler. What you want to do is the following:

```
float pay = calc(pieces);
```

> CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

You need to specify your real numbers as a float in order to save them into a float variable, as they are a double by default.

```
private float calc(int pieces)
{
    float pay = 0f;
    switch (pieces)
    {
        case 0:
            pay = 0f;
            break;
        case 1: // 1 to 199
            pay = pieces * 0.5f;
            break;
        case 2: // 200 to 399
            pay = pieces * 0.55f;
            break;
        case 3: // 400 to 599
            pay = pieces * 0.6f;
            break;
        default:
            pay = pieces * 0.65f;
            break;
    }
    return pay;
}
```

> CS1620 Argument 2 must be passed with the 'out' keyword.

Passing any values by reference must be explicitly defined using the out keyword. You can read about it on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx).

```
if ((int.TryParse(piecesTextBox.Text.Trim(), out pieces)))
        {
            calcButton.Enabled = true;
        }
```